# Why gradlew builds different jars on different machines?

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

We have the same source code on three machines:
- Machine 1: Fedora 27
- Machine 2: Fedora 27
- Machine 3: Windows 10

in the project we have a `gradlew` script of version 4.4.1.

Before building the gradle cache on all machines is empty. We are building with the commands `clean build`.

We found that the jar size on Machine 2 and Machine 3 is equal and both jars works as expected. But the jar file on Machine 1 is 4 Kbytes less that other jars and contains some bugs (Spring doesn't read properties from property files when we run the jar which was generated on the Machine 1).

Why is it happening? Why do we get a jar with errors on the 1 Machine if the source code is equal?

Also, all 3 machines have the same version of Java and Gradle.

Also, we made a virtual machine (VirtualBox) with Windows 10 on Machine 1 and installed the same version of Gradle and Java on the virtual machine. The jar was successfully built and it works.

Also, Machine 1 and Machine 2 has the same version of Groovy and Linux kernel.

The hardware on all 3 machines is different.

Comment: A hardware problem comes to mind ...

Comment: @Henry possible, because we really have no clue why is it happening.

Comment: Perhaps a race condition in the build scripts? Have you enabled parallelization in gradle?

Comment: @Matthias parallelization is disabled in gradle

Comment: I suggest running gradle with the --debug option and comparing the output on good and bad machines.